# Conditional constraints for continuous variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

How could we model conditional constraints for two continuous variables? Suppose the two variables are: $$x\geq0$$ $$y\in\mathbb R.$$ The conditions are: if $y>0$, then $x>0$ and if $y\leq0$, then $x=0$.

Comment: $(x,y \in \Bbb{R})~$ and $~(y > 0 \implies x > 0) ~$ and $~(y \leq 0 \implies x = 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant.  Introduce a binary variable $z$ and impose linear big-M constraints:
\begin{align}
\epsilon (1-z) \le x &\le M(1-z) \tag1 \\
-Mz + \epsilon (1-z) \le y &\le M (1-z) \tag2 \\
\end{align}

- If $z=0$, then $\epsilon \le x \le M$ and $\epsilon \le y \le M$.
- If $z=1$, then $0 \le x \le 0$ and $-M \le y \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I need to design constraints in such a way that $x$ should be dependent on the cases of $y$ without introducing any other binary variable in it. Similar to what we use to connect two binary variables

Comment: Your feasible region is not convex, so you cannot model this linearly without a binary variable.